# Excluding same type of transactions within 3 seconds

Tags: sql, teradata

For example, a table is like below

| Type | Time Stamp | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-25 14:21:00 | A |
| 1 | 2021-06-25 14:21:03 | B |
| 1 | 2021-06-25 14:21:06 | C |
| 1 | 2021-06-25 14:23:00 | D |
| 2 | 2021-06-25 14:21:02 | C |
| 2 | 2021-06-25 14:21:06 | C |
| 2 | 2021-06-25 14:21:09 | D |
| 3 | 2021-06-25 14:21:06 | E |

And the result I want is as below.
If there are a series of transactions with the same type every 3 seconds or less, I will print the last one only.

| Type | Time Stamp | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-06-25 14:21:06 | C |
| 1 | 2021-06-25 14:23:00 | D |
| 2 | 2021-06-25 14:21:02 | C |
| 2 | 2021-06-25 14:21:09 | D |
| 3 | 2021-06-25 14:21:06 | E |

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Simplifying Gordon's query using a default for LEAD and Teradata's proprietary QUALIFY keyword:

```
select *
from vt
qualify 
   lead(timestamp, 1, date '9999-12-31')
   over (partition by type
         order by timestamp) > timestamp_ + interval '3' second;
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want rows where the *next* row of the same type is more than three seconds ahead:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lead(timestamp) over (partition by type order by timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where next_timestamp is null or
      next_timestamp > timestamp + interval '3' second;
```

Comment: @AlbertoSinigaglia . . . That is why the code uses `partition by type`.

Comment: sorry, my eyes refused to see that part